# Post Hoc Pair-Wise Comparisons for the Chi-Square Test of Homogeneity of Proportions

Tags: r, chi-squared-test

I am looking for a "Post Hoc Pair-Wise Comparisons for the Chi-Square Test of Homogeneity of Proportions" (or an equivalent of it) Which is described here: http://epm.sagepub.com/cgi/content/abstract/53/4/951
Yet besides that article I can not find an R package to do this with, or any other form of software. I hope that I am just badly informed

My situation is of just making a Chi-Square test, on a 2 by X matrix. I found a difference, but I want to know which of the subjects is "responsible" for the difference.

This has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464680/is-there-a-pair-wise-posthoc-comparisons-for-the-chi-square-test-in-r) before, but it was unanswered. Has anything changed in the meantime? I am looking for this as well.

Comment: I'm confused. If it's just a 2x2 table, there are only 2 proportions, so only one pair of them to compare. What am I missing?

Comment: This is a hypothetical 2 by X, so it could be 2 by 5 or 10 or anything like that.

Comment: The [fifer](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fifer/index.html) package contains a function chisq.post.hoc() See [page 4](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fifer/fifer.pdf) for details

Answer (score 7):

Having a significant chi-square does not necessarily mean that ONE subject is different from the others. However, IF this is the case, one way to approach this is to fit a logistic regression model and follow it up with contrasts that compare each prediction with the average of the others.

Here's an example. First, a fake dataset:

```
> fake = data.frame(
+   subj = factor(1:5),
+   pos = c(34, 36, 40, 62, 35),
+   neg = c(66, 64, 60, 38, 65))
```

Fit a logistic regression model and get the deviance

```
> fake.glm = glm(cbind(pos, neg) ~ subj, family = binomial(), data = fake)

> anova(fake.glm)
Analysis of Deviance Table
Model: binomial, link: logit
Response: cbind(pos, neg)
Terms added sequentially (first to last)

     Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev
NULL                     4     22.486
subj  4   22.486         0      0.000
```

The deviance statistic is a chi-square test, but not the same as the Pearson chi-square often used. A chi-square of 22.486 with 4 d.f. is significant.

The **lsmeans** package provides one way to obtain post hoc contrasts. Other possibilities include **multcomp** and **effects**.

```
> library(lsmeans)
> ( fake.lsm = lsmeans(fake.glm, "subj") )
 subj     lsmean        SE df   asymp.LCL    asymp.UCL
 1    -0.6632942 0.2111002 NA -1.07704294 -0.249545496
 2    -0.5753641 0.2083333 NA -0.98368998 -0.167038315
 3    -0.4054651 0.2041241 NA -0.80554108 -0.005389135
 4     0.4895482 0.2060214 NA  0.08575368  0.893342771
 5    -0.6190392 0.2096570 NA -1.02995931 -0.208119103

Confidence level used: 0.95
```

The above table summarizes the predicted values of $\log\{p/(1-p)\}$, and ther SEs and confidence intervals. You may also obtain  a visual display of these results:

```
> plot(fake.lsm)
```

[image]

The following obtains estimates and associated $t$ statistics comparing each of these with the average of the others:

```
> contrast(fake.lsm, "del.eff")
 contrast    estimate        SE df    z.ratio p.value
 1 effect -0.38571416 0.2351174 NA -1.6405175  0.2523
 2 effect -0.27580157 0.2327922 NA -1.1847544  0.2952
 3 effect -0.06342777 0.2292697 NA -0.2766513  0.7821
 4 effect  1.05533890 0.2308552 NA  4.5714324  <.0001
 5 effect -0.33039540 0.2339036 NA -1.4125281  0.2630

P value adjustment: fdr method for 5 tests
```

We find that subject 4's prediction is significantly greater than the average of the others'. The FDR (false discovery rate) is the default adjustment for multiple testing when `del.eff` contrasts are specified. It seems appropriate for this kind of application.

If you prefer, you may instead do this analysis in terms of the predicted values of $p$, instead of the logits.

```
> ( fake.lsmp = regrid(fake.lsm, transform = TRUE) )
 subj prob         SE df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 1    0.34 0.04737088 NA 0.2471548 0.4328452
 2    0.36 0.04800000 NA 0.2659217 0.4540783
 3    0.40 0.04898979 NA 0.3039818 0.4960182
 4    0.62 0.04853864 NA 0.5248660 0.7151340
 5    0.35 0.04769696 NA 0.2565157 0.4434843

Confidence level used: 0.95
```

... and use similar commands on this object to obtain contrasts or a plot.

These methods are probably not exactly the same as the reference you link, but they get at the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate response. I am aware that the significance in my chisq is possibly caused by multiple groups differing significantly from eachother, which is why I was looking for the post hoc package that @user2521252 linked above. 

If for some reason that doesn't work, I'll definetely come back to your suggestion.

Comment: There are lots of other contrast families available in lsmeans, e.g. pairwise, Dunnett, etc. I used del.eff contrasts in my example because of the way you posed your question.